# SQL Server Query Notifications in Java

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, query-notifications

I've been searching online for a while, but with no luck so far. Is it possible to implement this in Java http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/144344/Query-Notification-using-SqlDependency-and-SqlCach? Is it supported by JDBC for SQL Server 2012?

Comment: Yea, I understand, but that's just an example. My question is if SQL Server Query Notifications can be implemented in JAVA at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to listen to SQL server notifications. You can configure MSSql Server to notify a Broker. There is [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) as an open source solution. So you need to connect MSSql Server to your broker and use JMS implementation to listen & retrieve notifications in java from the broker.

The question now is : is it possible to connect MSSql Server to any broker ? I will search for that and comeback to you.

Comment: After searching not very thorough. 
I can say for now is that I do not find how to connect to MSSQL Service broker in java. So the solution would be to make a bridge between MSSQL Service and a Broker with .NET as described in your link above. [Here](http://jawiseblog.blogspot.fr/2008/09/sql-server-integration-with-enterprise.html) there is a good article that might help you.

Comment: I just went to a programming event last night where this was demonstrated with .Net.  The takeaway for the non-.Net people was that it can be setup over any ODBC connection, but that catching the callback could be an issue depending on your ODBC/JDBC driver support.  I suppose an MQ or other bridge would work, but it would be best if the native JDBC driver would just support it.  :-)