# Table Level Notification in MSsql Database

Tags: javascript, java, sql, sql-server

Notification: How can i get notification(table name and row id) from Sql Server database when data insert,update into table.My Allication using java or javascript.Please advice.

Comment: You need to look up triggers.

Comment: My requirement is trigger can't insert into any other temp_table.

Comment: in oracle "USER_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION_REGS".

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm#JJDBC28816

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247679/sql-server-trigger-insert-values-from-new-row-into-another-table

Comment: and at that doc, i have know oracle using like trigger too.., what wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Query Notifications in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23659038/sql-server-query-notifications-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL, You just using tringger (like MySQL),

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName ON SourceOfYourTabe
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE  
AS
   // SOME QUERY TO PUSH YOUR NOTIF
GO
```

Refrence By: 

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm#JJDBC28816

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql

Comment: Using Trigger  how to get message notification in sql server dynamically.ex:postgres below:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg.notify_change() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    BEGIN
         PERFORM  pg_notify('tblexample','pg.tblexample');
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE TRIGGER table_change 
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON pg.tblexample
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE ph.notify_change();