# SQL Server DB event listener for java app

Tags: java, sql-server

Does anyone know of a way to listen to SQL Server change events via Java?  I found this link for SQL server query notifications, but it only seems to apply to .NET, and I need to do this in Java: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/query-notifications-in-sql-server

Comment: Possible duplicate: [SQL Server Query Notifications in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23659038/sql-server-query-notifications-in-java)